# ADB back up does not work when I backup file large

Tags: android, adb, backup

I used this command to backup data in root /data/data/package (about 5.4 Gb)

```
adb backup -f "C:\mybackup.ab" com.app.packagename
```

But it created .ab file about 2gb,
I tried many times and the file size created is very different : 1.5gb , sometimes 3gb , sometimes 3.5gb ,......

I have tried with my phone : xiaomi k30 (nonroot) and nox emulator (android 7 , root)

Please help me fix this problem

Comment: If the backup size is different this could be caused by a crash of the backup service on device. Have you verified the created backup files e.g. using [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor)? If they are defect than it might be a crashing backup service. Unfortunately there is nothing you can do to fix that.

Comment: Adb backup and Android backup service are two different things. Please correct your tags.

Comment: oh, I don't use Android Backup Extractor, but I did use 'adb restore' for the .ab files just created on other devices
it all makes the app crash

Comment: If the app crashes this does not mean that the backup failed. I am not sure how `adb backup` behaves if the app is running and constantly creates new files or writes to existing files. Also keys store in AndroidKeystore can't be included in a backup (even if you try to create a backup with root). So the backup may be incomplete.

Comment: What do you think is the cause of the app crash?

Comment: My computer configuration is core i7-10th , RAM 16gb
Nox emulator used 4 cores and ram 4gb 
it's not too bad for the backup to fail